# Import single sql table from whole db export

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to import a single database table from a large sql file? This would save me several hours, as I'm currently doing:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: have you tried? `mysql -u username -p databasename tableName < path/example.sql`

Comment: `$ mysql -u root --database=avails --table="main_creditmaster"  < /Users/david/Desktop/Avails/July2-Avails-Prod-Export 
Warning: mysql: ignoring option '--table' due to invalid value 'main_creditmaster'`

Comment: Yeah you put quotes which mysql interprets as a string `--table="main_creditmaster"`...of course you would have gotten an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the tablename option, using the tick marks around the table name:

```
mysql -u root --database=`avails` --table=`main_creditmaster` < /Users/david/Desktop/Avails/July2-Avails-Prod-Export
```